# numpy date issue - convert floating point year-week format to numpy's date format

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a floating point value representing the date with year-week format as follows:

```
201423.0000
```

where the 2014 is the year and 23 is the week number. How can I convert this floating point value to numpy's datetime format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
In [43]: a = 201423.0000

In [48]: date = np.datetime64(str(int(a // 100)), 'Y') + np.timedelta64(int(a%100), 'W')

In [49]: date
Out[49]: numpy.datetime64('2014-06-05')
```